# Android listen browser history last page

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

I get the browser history, but just want to get the information of visited pages here is my code below  and the same way I want to hear the newly added phone book contacts

```
public class HistoryObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public final String TAG = "HistoryObserver";

    public HistoryObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating new HistoryObserver");``
    }

    public HistoryObserver() {
        super(null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating a new HistoryObserver without a Handler");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        Log.d(TAG, "delivering self notifications");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange without uri: " + selfChange);
        //onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: " + selfChange + "\t " + uri.toString());

        String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE };
        String selection = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
        Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, selection, null, null);
        //this.startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
       int count= mCursor.getColumnCount();
      String COUNT=String.valueOf(count);
        Log.e("Browser sayac", COUNT);

        String title = "";
        String url = "";
        String date="";
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst() && mCursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

                title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE ));
                url = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
                 date =  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
                 Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);  

              SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy/HH:mm");
              Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
            String  finaldate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
              String smsDate = finaldate.toString();

                // Log.e("DTE", date);
                    Log.e("URL",title  );

                    Log.e("TARIH", smsDate);
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might I recommend a better title for your question?

Comment: I have just getting last page information (url,date,title)

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include an example of your log output? That might help us help you. Also, when you say "just want to get the information of visited pages," can you provide an example of what that information might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to

```
//add thread.sleep to delay the action because sometimes it takes around a second before the page history is added. you can use other delaying techniques though
try {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, selection, null, null);
//this.startManagingCursor(mCursor);
mCursor.moveToFirst(); // instead of movetolast
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ContentObserver, I'm guessing that what you want is to get the last visited page. The process is almost the same except that you just have to point the cursor to the last position by using the moveToLast() method.

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi") public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    Log.d(TAG, "onChange: " + selfChange + "\t " + uri.toString());

    String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL,Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE };
    String selection = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, selection, null, null);
    //this.startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    mCursor.moveToLast();
   int count= mCursor.getColumnCount();
  String COUNT=String.valueOf(count);
    Log.e("Browser sayac", COUNT);

            String title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE ));
            String url = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
             String date =  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE));
             Long timestamp = Long.parseLong(date);  

          SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy/HH:mm");
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        String  finaldate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
          String smsDate = finaldate.toString();

            // Log.e("DTE", date);
                Log.e("URL",title  );

                Log.e("TARIH", smsDate);



}
```

And of course, you need to register your ContentObserver for that to work. I would recommend for you to use Background Service to register the observer.

```
       private BrowserObserver browserObserver;
      browserObserver = new BrowserObserver(new Handler(), getBaseContext());
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, true, browserObserver);
```

and don't forget to add this permission in your manifest

Comment: I tried this code but does not get entered last page

Comment: what is it that you're getting then? are you getting the second last page?

Comment: its get two days ago entered page